# Compare list of 2 columns in a python dataframe and count the same item

Tags: python, list, dataframe

how to compare list of 2 columns in a python dataframe and count the same list between these 2 column in a dataframe. For example:

```
column A            |   column B
====================================
['a', 'b', 'c']     | ['a', 'b']
['a', 'b']          | ['a']
['b']               | ['a']
```

i want to get this result:

```
    column A            |   column B    | count_same_item
    ======================================================
    ['a', 'b', 'c']     | ['a', 'b']    | 2
    ['a', 'b']          | ['a']         | 1
    ['b']               | ['a']         | 0
```

really appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['count_same_item'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x['column A']) & set(x['column B'])), axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    column A column B  count_same_item
0  [a, b, c]   [a, b]                2
1     [a, b]      [a]                1
2        [b]      [a]                0
```